# What does the + operand between types mean?

Tags: rust, algebraic-data-types, static-typing

With this example from [core::any](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/any/index.html)

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::any::Any;

// Logger function for any type that implements Debug.
fn log<T: Any + Debug>(value: &T) {
    let value_any = value as &dyn Any;

    // try to convert our value to a String.  If successful, we want to
    // output the String's length as well as its value.  If not, it's a
    // different type: just print it out unadorned.
    match value_any.downcast_ref::<String>() {
        Some(as_string) => {
            println!("String ({}): {}", as_string.len(), as_string);
        }
        None => {
            println!("{:?}", value);
        }
    }
}

// This function wants to log its parameter out prior to doing work with it.
fn do_work<T: Any + Debug>(value: &T) {
    log(value);
    // ...do some other work
}

fn main() {
    let my_string = "Hello World".to_string();
    do_work(&my_string);

    let my_i8: i8 = 100;
    do_work(&my_i8);
}
```

This is the first time I’ve seen a **`+`**  operand between types `Any + Debug`. I’m assuming its like [algebraic types](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) and therefore would be an `Any` type with `Debug` type; however, I cannot find any docs under algebraic types in Rust.

What is the `+` actually doing here, what is it called? Where can I find the docs on this?

Comment: Tim gave you the answer. As for algebraic types: In Rust, product types are `struct`s and tuples, sum types are `enum`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`T: Any + Debug` is a [trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#trait-bounds). The type `T` must satisfy [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) **and** [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html), therefore the `+` sign is used here and it is not related to algebraic types. You can read more on traits at the [corresponding section in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html).

[This section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#specify-multiple-traits-with-) mentions the `+` sign.